# Get the first person dead after a certain date without limit and fetch

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
 PERSON (
   id,
   name,
   last_name,
   birth_date_year, 
   birth_date_month, 
   birth_date_day, 
   death_date_year, 
   death_date_month, 
   death_date_day
 )
```

And I have to write a PostgreSQL query that gets the first person dead after a certain another person (eg. 'Get the first person dead after "John Smith").

I can't use all SQL constructors (basically, only the functions in [W3C Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/)) and no OFFSET, LIMIT, ROWNUM, FETCH and TOP.
Subqueries are allowed.

PS: The result table must have only one person, not all people died after "john Smith" ordered by year, month and day.
I can't use LIMIT because the request explicitly says not to use it.
I don't know why the data is stored with 3 fields insteed of a single data field, the original database is not mine.

I can get all the people died after 'John Smith' with this simple query:

```
select person.birth_date_year, 
   person.birth_date_month, 
   person.birth_date_day, 
   person.death_date_year, 
   person.death_date_month, 
   person.death_date_day
from person
inner join person as "dead_person" on "dead_person"."name" = 'John Smith'
where
  person.end_date_year > "dead_person".death_date_year
  or (person.death_date_year = "dead_person".death_date_year
  and person.death_date_month > "dead_person".death_date_month)
  or (person.death_date_year = "dead_person".death_date_year
  and person.death_date_month = "dead_person".death_date_month
  and person.death_date_day > "dead_person".death_date_day);
order by person.death_date_year, 
  person.death_date_month, 
  person.death_date_day
```

But I don't know how to get only the first person dead from this result without using LIMIT, FETCH or ROWNUM.
In other cases I've used MAX or MIN to get the max/min value and compared it with the table again to get the full row, but in this case I can't use it because I have to get the lowest value from 3 fields instead of one and max/min doesn't accept multicolumn values.

Comment: all seems clear. what's the question?..

Comment: ANSI SQL includes OFFSET and FETCH FIRST.

Comment: hmmm, and if you don't try to solve you assignment how are you supposed to learn? Try something, research, do, then show your effort.

Comment: One tip, make a join between table Person and table Person. First side of join get "John Smith", other side of the join get the result you want. And as @JorgeCampos said, try and show your effort.

Comment: I also don't know why you cant use even LIMIT,  FETCH and OFFSET.

Comment: Why is the birth date stored in three columns instead  of a single `DATE` column?

Comment: Also: many of the SQL commands listed on W3fools are **not** standard ANSI SQL

Comment: In which column would the value  "John Smith" be stored?

Comment: Well, I think I wasn't clear enough. I've updated the post with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misread the question. You can not use ROWNUM.

So, there is other solution (there is always another :) ). Not simple, not beautiful, but works:

```
DROP TABLE PERSON

CREATE TABLE PERSON (
   id int,
   name varchar,
   last_name varchar,
   birth_date_year int, 
   birth_date_month int, 
   birth_date_day int, 
   death_date_year int, 
   death_date_month int, 
   death_date_day int
 )

 INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES(1, 'John','Smith',2000,1,1,2040,2,2);
 INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES(2, 'A','Aa',2000,1,1,2041,2,2);
 INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES(3, 'B','Ba',2000,1,1,2040,1,2);
 INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES(4, 'C','Ca',2000,1,1,2040,4,2);
 INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES(5, 'D','Da',2000,1,1,2040,4,2);

SELECT *
FROM person
INNER JOIN (
    -- select first id that die at same day, after 'John Smith' 
    SELECT min(person.id) id
    FROM (
        select "dead_person".id, min (make_timestamp(person.death_date_year, person.death_date_month, person.death_date_day, 0, 0, 0)) date_dead
        from person
        inner join person as "dead_person" on "dead_person".name ||  ' ' || "dead_person".last_name = 'John Smith'
        where
          person.death_date_year > "dead_person".death_date_year
          or (person.death_date_year = "dead_person".death_date_year
          and person.death_date_month > "dead_person".death_date_month)
          or (person.death_date_year = "dead_person".death_date_year
          and person.death_date_month = "dead_person".death_date_month
          and person.death_date_day > "dead_person".death_date_day)
        group by "dead_person".id
    ) dead_after
    INNER JOIN person
        ON dead_after.date_dead = make_timestamp(person.death_date_year, person.death_date_month, person.death_date_day, 0, 0, 0)
) dead_after
    ON dead_after.id = person.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I don't think we can use even _over_. Our professor says that there is a simply solution without using these constructors, but at present I am unable to find a solution that doesn't use a lot of subqueries or, at least, one of these constructors.

Comment: I misread the question. Answer updated. Can you use make_timestamp?

Comment: Thank you, i don't think we can use make_timestamp, but I've simply replaced the command with a mathematical expression that simulates the timestamp: "person.death_date_year * 10000 + person.death_date_month * 100 + person.death_date_day" and it works!

Comment: Great. That was a clever solution to avoid make_timestamp. Any way, the final result isn't pretty. If your professor show you other solution, please share :)